# Download files from all remote subdirectories to one local directory with WinSCP script file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

This gets all the `mp4` and `mkv` files into `K:\in`, but it also preserves the subdirectories they were in on the source drive. I want to end up with `mp4` and `mkv` files in `K:\in` without the subdirectors.

I end up with this in `K:\in`

```
K:\in\01.mkv
K:\in\abc\02.mkv
K:\in\def\03.mkv
```

and I want to end up with this

```
K:\in\01.mkv
K:\in\02.mkv
K:\in\03.mkv
```

Appreciate your time

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Users\MediaServer\Desktop\winscp.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command "open sftp://%SFTP_USER%:%SFTP_PASSWORD%@%SFTP_HOST% -hostkey=""%HOSTKEY%""" ^
     "cd /home3/cam4/" ^
     "lcd K:/in"^
     "get -filemask=*.mp4;*.mkv *"^
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with simple WinSCP scripting.

But if you switch to WinSCP .NET assembly, you can implement it easily.
See [WinSCP example for downloading all files from FTP/SFTP to the same local folder](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_files_to_same_folder).

---

Alternatively, keep your download script and flatten the downloaded directory structure ex-post locally.

```
for /r "c:\downloadpath" %%f in ("*.*") do move "%%f" "c:\targetpath\"
```

(also covered in the link above)